# Weird "Undefined Reference ..." error despite using target link libraries

Tags: ros, catkin-make, target-link-libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Every one,

I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04,

In one of my code I'm using a BIoTacHand class from the [biotac ros driver](http://wiki.ros.org/biotac_driver), the class header file is in the biotac_sensors package. So basically, I have three biotac fingers attached to a barrett wam arm, and I aim to collect the biotac data while moving the wam, so I initialized a BioTacHand class in my wam running code as the following:

```
using namespace barrett;
using detail::waitForEnter;
using namespace biotac;
//ProductManager PM("/etc/barrett/bus1/default.conf");
//Global parameters for BioTacHandClass
biotac::BioTacHandClass LEFT_HAND("left_hand"); //initialize the biotac hand class
```

The code used to work fine, however this afternoon when I changed some other parts in the code and recompiled, the compiler threw out the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable /home/robot/yzheng_ws/devel/lib/wam_node/wam_node_l
CMakeFiles/wam_node_l.dir/src/wam_node_l.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/robot/yzheng_ws/src/wam_robot/wam_node/src/wam_node_l.cpp:116: undefined reference to   `biotac::BioTacHandClass::BioTacHandClass(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/home/robot/yzheng_ws/src/wam_robot/wam_node/src/wam_node_l.cpp:116: undefined reference to `biotac::BioTacHandClass::~BioTacHandClass()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: *** [/home/robot/yzheng_ws/devel/lib/wam_node/wam_node_l] Error 1   
make[1]: *** [wam_robot/wam_node/CMakeFiles/wam_node_l.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However, I've added the biotac_sensors package as a catkin component, as used `target_link_libraries` tags, here is my CMakelist for the wam_node package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(wam_node)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs std_srvs sensor_msgs geometry_msgs trajectory_msgs roscpp roslib tf wam_msgs rosbag biotac_sensors cheetah_lib)
catkin_package(
DEPENDS Barrett
CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs std_srvs sensor_msgs geometry_msgs trajectory_msgs roscpp tf wam_msgs roslib rosbag biotac_sensors cheetah_lib
INCLUDE_DIRS 
LIBRARIES 
)

include_directories(include
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

find_package(Barrett REQUIRED)
link_directories(${BARRETT_LIB_DIRS} src)
include_directories(${BARRETT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${BARRETT_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(wam_node_l src/wam_node_l.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wam_node_l ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${BARRETT_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(wam_node_l ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}     wam_msgs_gencpp)
```

and here is the gist of package.xml of the wam_node package:

```
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_srvs</build_depend>
<build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>trajectory_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>roslib</build_depend>
<build_depend>bullet</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>
<build_depend>wam_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>wam_srvs</build_depend>
<build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>
<build_depend>biotac_sensors</build_depend>
<build_depend>cheetah_lib</build_depend>

<run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>std_srvs</run_depend>
<run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>trajectory_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>roslib</run_depend>
<run_depend>bullet</run_depend>
<run_depend>tf</run_depend>
<run_depend>wam_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>wam_srvs</run_depend>
<run_depend>rosbag</run_depend>
<run_depend>biotac_sensors</run_depend>
<run_depend>cheetah_lib</run_depend>
```

Does any one have any idea ? The answer I found after searching through are all about missing the `target_link_libraries` tag, also the BioHandClass `IS NOT A TEMPLATE CLASS`.
Thx!

---

EDIT:
The change I made to the CMakeLists.txt of the wam_node package:

```
 add_executable(wam_node_l src/wam_node_l.cpp) 
 target_link_libraries(wam_node_l ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${BARRETT_LIBRARIES} biotacpub)
 add_dependencies(wam_node_l ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} wam_msgs_gencpp)
```

---

EDIT:
The CMakeLists.txt for the biotac_sensors package I'm using is the following:

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
  project(biotac_sensors)`
 
  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp cheetah_lib message_generation std_msgs)
  
  include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

 add_message_files(
 DIRECTORY msg
 FILES
 BioTacData.msg
 BioTacHand.msg
 BioTacTime.msg
 )

 generate_messages(
 DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
 )

 add_library(biotacpub src/biotac.c src/cheetah.c src/biotac_hand_class.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(biotacpub ${catkin_LIBRARIES} -ldl)

 catkin_package(
 DEPENDS 
 CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp cheetah_lib std_msgs
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES biotacpub
 )

 add_executable(biotac_pub src/biotac.c src/cheetah.c src/biotac_hand_class.cpp src/biotac_pub.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(biotac_pub ${catkin_LIBRARIES} -ldl)
 add_dependencies(biotac_pub ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp)

 install(TARGETS biotac_pub
 ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
 LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
 RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262874/weird-%22undefined-reference-...%22-error-despite-using-target-link-libraries./) by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-05-31**:
Did you include the `biotac_sensors/biotac_hand_class.h`?

**Comment by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on 2017-05-31**:
Hi DavidN,
Yes I did that, here is a snapshot of the code:
`43   #include <biotac_sensors/biotac_hand_class.h>`
`44  #include <biotac_sensors/BioTacHand.h>`

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-05-31**:
Can you try to add `biotac_sensor` to the target_link_libraries so that you will have something like this: `target_link_libraries(wam_node_l ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${BARRETT_LIBRARIES} biotac_sensor)`

**Comment by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on 2017-05-31**:
HI DavidN, thanks for the replay. Instead of biotac_sensors, I added the library generated in biotac_sensors, called biotacpub to the target_link_libraries and it compiled successfully. You I can see the change I made in the edited question.

**Comment by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on 2017-05-31**:
Since I exported the biotacpub library of biotac_sensors package using  `catkin_package()`. Then if I added the biotac_sensors package as a catkin component in wam_node package, wouldn't `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` include everything from biotac_sensors ?

**Comment by [Haibo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27575/haibo/) on 2017-06-01**:
If `biotac_sensors` package exported `biotac_sensor` library,  it is enough to use `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`. However, it seems `biotac_sensors` package did not use `catkin_package()` to export the library.

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-06-01**:
It is great that you found the solution. Please post the actual solution as the answer and close this question. :)

**Comment by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on 2017-06-01**:
Hi Haibo,
I double checked the CMakeLIsts.txt file in biotac_sensors, it did use
`catkin_package( DEPENDS  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp cheetah_lib std_msgs INCLUDE_DIRS include LIBRARIES biotacpub )`

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-06-01**:
Which version of CMakeList.txt you were looking at? Do you have the biotac_sensors source code with you? According to this link, the field `LIBRARIES` is empty: https://github.com/kth-ros-pkg/biotac_driver/blob/hydro/biotac_sensors/CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on 2017-06-01**:
Hi DavidN,
Thx for the reply. I've added the CMakeLIsts.txt file for the biotac_sensors package I use in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved, see the edit I made! However I still don't understand why this error would happen, everything seems normal.

---

Originally posted by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0